# Bash Script is Not Taking 2nd Argument in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins-pipeline

> Here is my script to get telnet status

```
#!/bin/bash
IP=$1;
PORT=$2;
exec 3> /dev/tcp/$IP/$PORT
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then echo "PortOpen";else echo "PortClosed";fi
```

> I am calling the func in my pipeline stage

```
def telnetTest (namespace, release, port) {
script {
    // Getting Service IP
    def serviceIP = sh (
            returnStdout: true,
            script: "kubectl get svc -n ${namespace} | grep ${release} | awk '{print \$4}'"
    )
    echo "ServiceIP: ${serviceIP}"
    // Checking Service IP is Exsisting ?
    if (serviceIP.equals('')) {
        echo "ERROR: Getting service IP failed"
        sh 'exit 1'
    }
    // Telnet Testing 
    sh "chmod +x telnetPort.sh"
    
    def telnetTesting = sh (
            returnStdout: true,
            script: "./telnetPort.sh ${serviceIP} ${port}"
    )

    echo "${telnetTesting}"        
}
```

}

> Pipeline Stage

```
Pipeline {
   environment {
      NAMESPACE = default
      RELEASE = test
      PORT = 9040
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Telnet Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    telnetTest ("${NAMESPACE}", "${RELEASE}", "${PORT}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

> Now its taking only first arg passing to the script
> Any one let me know why & where i am going wrong

Comment: SO-formal:  Why do yo quote your own sentences? Content-wise: Did you try `telnetPort.sh` in Bash and does it work there? Is the last code section from the Console Output of your build (if yes, is that all [that's relevant] and where are the `[Pipeline] ` line prefixes then)?

Comment: Yes it worked in bash when I Run that script with 2 arguments.

Comment: And the answers to the last questions are?

Comment: Yes it is the console output

Comment: Is that all [that's relevant] and where are the [Pipeline] line prefixes then?

Comment: I just posted a part, it's there

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you write `port`, and in the defining line, you wrote `PORT`.

Comment: While the definition of Jenkins tasks using Groovy is not really my field of experience, but: . When you call `telnetTest`, you pass it, I think, the correct port (I would verify this for the safe side inside `telnetTest` by doing a  `echo "port: $port"`, but you don't pass it to `telnetTesting` by parameter. Can Groovy access local variables from an outer scope? If it can't, the `$port` inside `telnetTesting` is perhaps understood as an environment variable, rather than a Groovy variable. The whole thing looks more like a Groovy problem to me; I suggest thta you add a _groovy_ tag.